# Can R access internet whilst running as an external script in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, r

I run the R portion of the code in Rstudio, and it works fine.
But when I call it inside SQL Server, it runs successfully, but cant return any results, only "I've got nothin'" which is the default error of the wikifacts package when it cant find a result to return.

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script       
                    @language = N'R',
                    @script = N' 

                    library(wikifacts)
                    query <- "Microsoft"
                    answer <- as.data.frame(wiki_define(query, sentence = 1))
                    print(answer)
                    '
```

Im just wondering if its being blocked along the way, or not possible to call external data from SQL server? And what a possible workaround could be?

Comment: You can not use R code in a Transact-SQL statement. They are completely different languages.

Comment: Err.. thats not true. SQL Server natively supports R and Python languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved..!

For anyone who wants to know, I had to disable outbound firewall rules for SQL server.

Comment: Maz, do you know if the firewall rules were defaults or manually created? That is, does a proper SQL Server instance automatically add firewalls rules from code operating within its environment, was the block a default Windows server action, or was it manually put into place as a "good practice" by the sysadmin and/or DBA? (It seems a reasonable safety, and I'm not questioning the firewall rule, just wondering the scope of the problem.) Thanks!

Comment: it seems to be installed by default. Now knowing what to look for, ive read that the rules are added when installing SQL Machine Learning Services.

Comment: Lol, a year on and an upgrade from SQL Server 2019 to 2022 and I ran into the same error. Totally forgot about this... googled it, and found my own question/solution that fixed it again :)